# PayPal Api How to get shipping address

Tags: paypal

```
addressArray = [details.payer.address.address_line_1, details.payer.address.address_line_2 ,
                details.payer.address.admin_area_2, details.payer.address.admin_area_1 ,details.payer.address.postal_code]
```

currently I am getting the billing address, I was wondering about how do I get the shipping address on the paypal api. This is using javascript

Answer (score 1):

```
var test = details.purchase_units[0].shipping.address.address_line_1
```

I found it out we can use this to get the shipping address